# Postgresql Logical Replication issue

Tags: replication, postgresql-10

I had a server set up as a subscriber to our production server using postgreSQLs new logical replication feature.  It seemed to be working well, however yesterday I needed to install the **postgresql10-contrib10.4-1** package.

Now, for some reason the subscription is broken and errors out when I try to resubscribe with the following error message:

```
ERROR: could not create replication slot "subrep1": ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/pgsql-10/lib/pgoutput.so": /usr/pgsql-10/lib/pgoutput.so: undefined symbol: is_publishable_relation
SQL state: XX000
```

First off, is this an issue with the publisher or the subscriber?  The subscriber is pg 10.4 and the publisher is **pg 10.2**.

Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Please check publishers binaries. Might be the case when binaries were updated but service wasn't restarted